# Is there a way to use a pointer to struct inside the struct without naming the struct?

Tags: c, struct

Currently I am using this `struct`.

```
typedef struct node {
    struct node *prev;
    struct node *next;
    size_t elem_size;
    void *data;
} dll_node;
```

I want to use 2 pointers to the `struct` `prev` and `next` without naming the `struct` as `node` but by using the typedef `dll_node` inside the `struct`. How can I do that?

I tried using

```
dll_node *next;
```

instead of the current one but I am getting the error unknown type name : 'dll_node'.

Comment: Constructive criticism : explain the downvote so I can ask better question next time

Comment: Not my downvote, but perhaps you could just motivate your question?

Comment: @JensGustedt Didn't get you. What do you mean by motivating?

Comment: You could always use the same identifier for both the `struct` and the `typedef` in a forward declaration, if the "waste" of an identifier is what is bothering you.

Comment: Why don't you want to name the `struct`? that sounds not like a very useful restriction to me.

Comment: @JensGustedt I am trying to improve my basics of data structures [by getting review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/29213/review-implementation-of-stack-by-using-pointers-in-c). I was suggested to make a linked list and create stacks, queues around that for minimizing code in the linked review of my implementation. So I am trying to make a generic doubly linked list and a stack wraper around that for code reuse. You got me correctly that it is the waste of a identifier that I am trying to eliminate as I wanted my reusable code to introduce minimum identifiers in client code.

Comment: @JensGustedt Small things add up so I wanted to improve my code in every way I can think of before posting a question for a review. The people on codereview have given me great suggestions so I don't want to waste their time without improving my code myself. You should make that an answer. That is the best solution of the current problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution to avoid using multiple identifiers to refer to the same type is this idiom:

```
typedef struct dll_node dll_node;

struct dll_node {
  dll_node* prev;
  ...
};
```

Note that the `typedef` serves at the same time as a forward declaration of the `struct`.

Note also that this still defines one typename in the `struct` name space and one in the identifier name space, but this is the best you can get in C.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to do what you are doing. The compiler has no idea what `dll_node` is as it determines the amount of bytes the structure will require when allocated. Do this:

```
struct node;

typedef struct node dll_node;

struct node {
  dll_node *next;
  dll_node *prev;
  size_t elem_size;
  void *data;
};
```

... or  a method I personally like to use (as you are often dealing with pointers to structs):

```
struct node;

typedef struct node *dll_node;

struct node {
  dll_node next;
  dll_node prev;
  size_t elem_size;
  void *data;
};
```

Comment: I wanted to know whether it is possible to do that without naming it beforehand. You named it.

Comment: @AseemBansal no its not

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef struct node dll_node;

struct node {
dll_node *prev;
dll_node *next;
size_t elem_size;
void *data;
};
```

It's not possible to do without naming it before hand, as the compiler doesn't know what it is, if it is not declared initially.

Answer (score 1):

The C compiler needs to see a type declared before its use, as this information is crucial to the parser. Therefore, it is simply impossible to use a type before its name has been defined.

Answer (score 0):

I do not really understand if I grasp your point but I think that what you can do is to implement some short of polymorphic `struct`s. In your case `node` is a tag and `dllnode` a type. Tags are necessary to refer to a struct within the struct itself and that is why your last statement fails and only `struct node` is legal. You can't have a dynamic behavior in a static design. So if I were you I would change the design to something like this:

```
struct dllnode{
    node super;
    dllnode *next;
    dllnode *prev;
    size_t  elem_size;
    void    *payload;
    uint32_t flag;
};

struct node{
   node   *next;
   node   *prev;
   size_t elem_size;
   void   *payload;
};
```

So you can have a primitive type `node` in you code and multiple "child" types like `dllnode` or any other node type you need! By casting the father (node) as a kid (dllnode) you can exchange values between the two structs. That is because the C standard says that the first member of a struct is aligned to the beginning of the struct.
For example:

```
void add_dllnode(struct node *s)
{
    struct dllnode *self = (struct dllnode *) s;
    self->next = s->next;
    self->prev = s->prev;
    self->elem_size = s->elem_size;
    self->payload = s->payload;
    // you can now do treat node as if it's dllnode and probably add it to
    // one of your lists
}
```

In addition whenever you create a `node` you can tune the flag member to something like `NODE_TYPE_DLL` or `NODE_TYPE_OTHER` and use it as a condition for your invocations, e.g.:

```
struct node s;
init_node(s);
...
if(((s->flag) & NODE_TYPE_DLL))
    add_dllnode(s);
else
    ...

...
```